# Where does `dbcontext.savechanges()` save data when no connection string

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working with Microsoft's documentation and learning c#. I am copying an example of [databinding with winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms#option-2-define-a-model-using-database-first).

The example works, but where is the data stored? I checked my folder, there is no mdf file, and my computer doesn't have SQL Server installed, but when I added something to the table, close the program and reopen it , the data is still there. Where is the data stored?

Comment: Visual studio comes with SqlExpress included.

Comment: Thank you,I got it.